# copy generic small array into larger generic array in a const fn

Tags: rust

I have an array of type [T; CURR] and I want to copy it into a [T; MAX] array inside of a const fn OR a macro (I could use either) (where MAX >= CURR). The situation for it is a bit odd, but doing this would be the easiest way. I've tried slices, but they aren't const, for loops which aren't const, unsafe functions copy which aren't stable for constant, and libraries with functions like concat_arrays! which typically end me up with other errors like "can't use generic parameters from outer function". What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: What do you want to fill `CURR..MAX` with?

Comment: I'm afraid you can't do that. At least, I can't come up with a way.

Comment: I ended up using mem::transmute from zeroed bytes of the same size. I need to correctly handle Copy and Drop now, which is a bit difficult.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `while` loop instead of a `for` loop and get about the same effect.

something like this, as a baseline:

```
const SMALL: usize = 2;
const LARGE: usize = 3;
const fn MAKE_BIG<T: std::marker::Copy>(small_arr: [T;SMALL]) -> [T;LARGE] {
    let mut looper = 1;
    let mut big_arr: [T;LARGE] = [small_arr[0];LARGE];
    while looper < SMALL {
        big_arr[looper] = small_arr[looper];
        looper += 1;
    }
    return big_arr;
}
```

This does have some issues though, for instance it doesn't work in the case of `small_arr` having a length of 0. This can be remedied by adding a request for a default in the function signature

```
const SMALL: usize = 2;
const LARGE: usize = 3;
const fn MAKE_BIG<T: std::marker::Copy>(small_arr: [T;SMALL],default: T) -> [T;LARGE] {
    let mut looper = 0;
    let mut big_arr: [T;LARGE] = [default;LARGE];
    while looper < SMALL {
        big_arr[looper] = small_arr[looper];
        looper += 1;
    }
    return big_arr;
}
```